# chained commands to create directories on a remote server

Tags: ssh, find, ls, cut

To get rsync cronjob working, I need to first create the dir tree on the remote server before running rsync. The local directories shall mirrored (w/o content) to the remote server. I'm strugglying to do that.

What I need is stg like this :

```
find /home/local_directories/onedir/* -type d -exec sh -c "ls -dlts {}"  \; | 
    cut -d" " -f10 | uniq | ssh user@server mkdir -p /tmp/{xargs}
```

The hard point is how to get the last pipe running ?

EDIT: the rsync command is like this (tried also with -R):

```
/usr/bin/rsync -e ssh -arz --stats --force /home/local_directories/onedir/ user@server:port:/exitsing/path/to/remote/dir/
```

The source tree is a svn hotcopy (/conf, /db, /hooks, /dav, ...)

Thx

Comment: Can you add your `rsync` command along with a sample source directory tree and the desired target directory tree?  I don't know if you need to be running `mkdir` repeatedly on the target host.

Comment: `cut -d" " -f10` is probably wrong.  Are you trying to get the directory name?  Or what it points to if it's a symlink?  Or something else?

Comment: Please [don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: Indeed, once we know what `-exec sh -c "ls -dlts {}"` is for, then we can replace it with `find -printf` or `stat` or whatever.

Comment: @Mikel,@Dennis :I agree this is an ugly way to get the sub directories path from /home/local_directories/onedir

Comment: `rsync` does not support `user@server:port:/path`.  You need `rsync -e "ssh -p port" ... user@server:/path`.

Comment: I think you'd better start from the start.  Clearly explain what you're trying to do and we can help with a solution.

Comment: @Dennis: Many thx for the useful link as well as for another great one you gave elsewhere about [process management](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear why you need to make all those directories using `mkdir`.

The only directory you should need to create is the destination directory itself, and that's only if it doesn't already exist.  `rsync` will create all the subdirs if you use the `-a` or `-v` option.

Something like this should be sufficient:

```
destdir="/home/local_directories/onedir.bak"  # or wherever it should go
ssh user@server "mkdir \"$destdir\""
rsync -a /home/local_directories/onedir/ user@server:"$destdir"
```

Or more correctly (only making the directory if it doesn't exist):

```
destdir="/home/local_directories/onedir.bak"
ssh user@server 'destdir="'"$destdir"'"; test -d "$destdir" || mkdir -p "$destdir"'
rsync -a /home/local_directories/onedir/ user@server:"$destdir"
```

---

But, if you *really* have to do this, and for some reason the `ls -ltds` *really* is required, then you would have to fix your `{xargs}` bit to get it running.

The most correct and efficient way I can think of to do the last bit is:

```
find ... |
    ssh user@server 'while IFS=$'"\n"' read -r dir; do test -d "$dir" || mkdir -p "$dir"; done'
```

The idea behind this is that we only start `find` and `ssh` once.  We start `find` and `ssh` together in a pipeline, with `find` sending its output to the remote server over `ssh`.

`find` produces one line of output per file, then the `while read` loop on the other side reads one line at a time, and does something with it (in this case, makes the directory).

If you were using `xargs`, it would be running `ssh` multiple times, which will make things slower.

Better, but a bit more complicated, is:

```
find ... -print0 |
    ssh user@server 'while read -r -d "$(printf "\000")" -r dir; do test -d "$dir" || mkdir -p "$dir"; done'
```

It's better because it handles weird characters in files, including newlines, which are very rare, and a bad idea, but better to handle them just in case.

---

So as far as I see it, you should just be doing something like:

```
find /home/local_directories/onedir/ -type d -print0 |
    ssh user@server 'while read -r -d "$(printf "\000")" -r dir; do test -d "$dir" || mkdir -p "$dir"; done'
```

Comment: rsync is used many times in a threaded bash script. It fails in some cases when remote dir tree does not exist or may have disappeared for other reasons on the remote server.

Comment: OK, so next can you explain what you want `ls -dlts | cut -d" " -f10` to do?  There are some better ways.

Comment: this is an ugly way to get the sub directories path from /home/local_directories/onedir, actually even worse : find /home/onedir/* -type d -exec sh -c "ls -dltsha {}"  \; | cut -d" " -f10 | uniq | sed -e "s/.*onedir//" - Currently strugglying with the find/while method that I did not know

Comment: thx, that helped a lot to get it done in a proper way.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what you're trying to achieve here.  I use rsync all the time and have never had to pre-make any directories on the server.

```
rsync -avP /home/local_directories/onedir/ user@server:/where/to/sync/to/
```

should just mirror the whole tree under onedir from local to remote.

Comment: remote server dir tree may change in some cases.

Comment: thx to your comment, I also checked the rsync command threads and could notice that it should NOT include the port in _user@server:PORT_ IF the command is keychained via ssh, otherwise it fails saying the remote dir does not exist.